# Strange Delphi integer multiplication behavior

Tags: delphi, math

I'm working on some ancient Delphi code and I've come across something which I don't quite understand.

```
[bla is set to 130245932]

outresult := ((bla * 1103516849) + 12359);

[outresult is equal to -413953101]
```

How does multiplying two positive numbers result in a negative number? And why is it that when I take the bla variable out of the equation and just use the integer directly (like this)

```
outresult := ((130245932 * 1103516849) + 12359);
```

I receive an error before the app even compiles

```
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(60): E2099 Overflow in conversion or arithmetic operation
```

Some genius would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Google: "Integer Overflow"

Comment: Should have posted as an aswer because I'd give you the vote, you've helped me immensely.

Comment: You could have just looked up that error. Please google the errors you get before making SO questions about them. You would have gotten [this page](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/E2099_Overflow_in_conversion_or_arithmetic_operation_(Delphi)) which explains it.

Comment: I was going to flag this as a duplicate, but searching SO for '[delphi] "integer overflow"' did not yield anything satisfying.  Maybe it's here, but it's not easy to find (and SO is meant to contain useful answers - even if they can be found elsewhere via Google)

Comment: I always use Google to find stuff on SO. Just restrict Google to stackoverflow by adding `site:stackoverflow.com` to your Google query. And they are very up-to-date. Questions asked minutes ago show up on Google searches...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Alright, I'll make this an answer.

The error message should be pretty clear. You have an integer overflow here:

```
130245932 * 1103516849
```

because `130245932 * 1103516849 = 143728580475708268` which is too large to fit into a 32-bit integer.

Answer (score 6):

It's based on the way memory is represented inside your system.  Basically, you've only got 32 bits per integer.  For a signed integer, one bit is used for the sign; this gives you a value range from negative to positive 2^31 (approximately 2 billion).  If you go outside that range, the system breaks down.

If you need large integers, try using `Int64` instead of `integer`.  If you need larger integers than that, check out the `BigInteger` type in [DeHL.](http://code.google.com/p/delphilhlplib/)

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing an integer overflow, and I thought you might be curious about the specific result you saw.

Your initial multiplication

(130245932 * 1103516849) = 143728580475708268

...results in integer overflow, and in 32-bit math the resulting "wrap-around" generates:

(143728580475708268 mod 2^32) - 2^32 = -413965460

...and then your equation adds 12359:

-413965460 + 12359 = **-413953101** (the result you saw, [Q.E.D.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.))

Hope this helps